# Twilio MMS with Node.js - Sending multiple media files

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, mms

The Twilio docs indicate that each MMS can have up to 10 media file attachments but the Node.js example only shows 1 attachment:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
 client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+16518675309", 
    from: "+14158141829", 
    body: "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!", 
    mediaUrl: "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg"  
 }, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
 });
```

I would have expected the mediaUrl property to be an Array of strings not a single value.  How do you indicate  more than one media attachment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely supply an array here if you have more than one mediaUrl to send. The code:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
 client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+16518675309", 
    from: "+14158141829", 
    body: "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!", 
    mediaUrl: ["http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg", "http://another-image.com/image.jpg"]
 }, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
 });
```

Will work just as well as using a string if you only have one image.

Under the hood, the Node.js helper library uses the [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options) module to turn parameters into a form encoded POST body. So, when you use an array of mediaUrls, like in my example, it will get turned into:

> 'to=%2B16518675309&from=%2B14158141829&body=Hey%20Jenny!%20Good%20luck%20on%20the%20bar%20exam!&**mediaUrl**=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm2.static.flickr.com%2F1075%2F1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg&**mediaUrl**=http%3A%2F%2Fanother-image.com%2Fimage.jpg'

Whilst that's a bit hard to read, I've highlighted the two instances of mediaUrl in the parameters. Twilio interprets the two values as a list of URLs and delivers your two images in the MMS.

Let me know if this helps!

**edit**

If you want to do this with TwiML, see the example below or [in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message?code-sample=code-message-with-nested-nouns&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x):

```
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const response = new MessagingResponse();
const message = response.message();
message.body('Hello Jenny');
message.media('https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png');
message.media('https://demo.twilio.com/bunny.png');

console.log(response.toString());
```

To add more media, just keep using the `media` method on the response, you can add up to 10 media items this way.

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting the answer so that other users can easily see that it solves the problem? Thanks!

Comment: philnash can you show an example of this with TwiML? (nodejs version of the library that makes the XML for you?)

Comment: Hey @JosephAstrahan, I've updated my answer with a TwiML example too.